# spaCy PhraseMatcher running out of memory/utilizing 100% CPU

Tags: memory, cpu-usage, spacy, matcher

I am trying to create a `PhraseMatcher` with 20 million patterns. For example:

```
terms = [''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k = 4)) for i in range(20000000)]
nlp = English()
matcher_large = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr = 'LOWER')
terms_large = list(nlp.tokenizer.pipe(terms))
matcher_large.add('Terms', None, *terms_large)
```

This is causing the kernel to die in Jupyter, or the process to get killed in the terminal. It was also running at 100% CPU. Is there a less memory-intensive way to create this matcher? I thought about creating matchers in chunks, but I don't want to end up with hundreds of matchers.

Comment: The PhraseMatcher is efficient but 20M is just too many patterns. What kinds of strings are you trying to match? There is probably a better approach than using a Matcher if you have 20M things.

Comment: @polm23 What would be the better approach? I have tried using a PhraseMatcher with 10M patterns, and when I actually used the matcher on my documents it was perfectly fine. It's just the process of creating the matcher itself

Comment: If you have 20M patterns I would expect that there is a part of speech pattern or something else you can match on instead, but it depends on what you are matching. Are these names of people, place names, chemical names...?

Answer (score 1):

It's true that the `PhraseMatcher` may not be the best choice this many patterns, but you can add patterns incrementally rather than creating a huge list up front and passing a likewise huge number of args at once to the `add` method:

```py
for doc in nlp.tokenizer.pipe(terms):
    matcher.add("Terms", [doc]) # newer API
```

Jupyter notebooks often have a relatively low default memory limit, which is probably what you're running into.